# Visual Studio 2010 crashes when creating or opening new xamarin/mono Android application solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'v installed xamarin on my w7x64 with vs2010 sp1 - after setting up i tried to create my 1rst "hello world" Android Application (step by step with this guide: [Xamarin Hello World Demo](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/getting_started/hello_world%29))
but when the project is loading (create) VS crashes...

As far as i can see there is nothing useful in the log (devenv.exe /log)
But in the the application-eventlog i can find the following error

(cutout) 
P1: devenv.exe

P2: 10.0.40219.1

P3: 4d5f2a73

P4: Xamarin.AndroidDesigner

P5: 1.0.0.0

P6: 4fad4cd6

P7: 2ee

P8: 10

P9: System.NullReferenceException

P10:

Additional Information:
I have installed DevExpress in my VS.. but by unloading these plugins the problem still exists.

Does anyone have the same problem or a solution for me?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin are looking at this right now - there are some suggested workarounds on http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/Visual-Studio-2010-crashes-when-opening-a-new-or-existing-Mono-for-Android-project-after-upgrade-to-1-td5709541.html

Comment: Thanks! - The currently last post on this site got the solution:

"...This will be fixed in the next release. As a workaroud, try adding the java bin directory (the one that contains the 'java' command) to the PATH."